# Error in Terminal: no such file or directory: /dev/fd/12export - thread 'main' panicked at 'failed printing to stdout: Broken pipe (os error 32)

Tags: error-handling, terminal

can someone help me solve/remove these 2 problems in my Mac terminal? I cannot understand why they are appearing and how to fix them. They are appearing every time I open a new terminal window!

I have installed php, node and composer using brew and an ssh key for gitlab.

[image]

Comment: It is a rust problem. Has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: how to solve it?

Comment: Just read the last line. You need to [set an environment variable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106778/how-do-i-set-environment-variables-on-os-x) which is set to `RUST_BACKTRACE=1`.

Answer (score 3):

I just ran into this as well, It was a syntax error in my terminal profile.

I had to open and examine my various .zshrc .profile so on and so forth.  One of them had an export on the same line as an eval

Issue:

```
eval "$(starship init zsh)"export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
```

Fixed:

```
eval "$(starship init zsh)"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/mysql-client/bin:$PATH"
```